# How much does AWS charge for data transfer between AZs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have a huge data say 1000GB that will need to move from one EC2 instance in *us-east-1a* to *us-east-1b* using private IPs.

Problem:
We are planning to setup multi az MySQL cluster which will be having 1 master and 5 replicas spread across different AZs. But we are concerned about the data replicated across to maintain the master-slave setup.

We wanted to know what would be the total cost incur during this operation in data transfer amongst different AZs?

Note: We have a NAT gateway to communicate to the internet from the instances which are in private subnet. These instances are in the private subnet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**$0.01/GB *in each direction*** where *in each direction* means that you’ll pay **$10** for your 1000GB of data going out from the first instance and than **another $10** for data coming in to the second instance. See [**Data Transfer within the same AWS Region**](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/) for more details.

You may also consider other options. E.g. create a snapshot from your data volume and restore it to a new volume in the other region that you can then attach to your second instance.

Hope that helps!